# Concatenated mp3 stop playing at 15s on some players (e.g. iTunes)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

I have [mp3 file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/hrvddxhfxhlt3yogqzwb4/tmp_audio_file_94562_with_ads.mp3?rlkey=svgbe44z4kayhtfhm9vmx2nva&dl=0) and I can not figure out why it stops playing at `15s` even thought it is `12 minutes` long.

`ffprobe` returns:

```
Duration: 00:12:02.30, start: 0.023021, bitrate: 131 kb/s
```

I figured that there is some sort of "stop" meta tag which is visible in e.g. iTunes

[image]

I also inspected mp3 file with e.g. [`MP3 scan+Repair`](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/40263/mp3-scanrepair) (mac) and I see this message:

```
MPEG stream error (424064), resynchronized successfully. Wrong number of MPEG data bytes specified in Xing header (11690192 instead of 11557248).
```

I see that app `MP3 scan & Repair` is able to fix the issue within milliseconds (no re-encoding is needed) and I want to do the same with sort of ffmpeg command. Any idea how can I fix this?